# encrypt format a picture

Tags: image, encryption

what format is this? how can I encrypt a picture into this?

`unsigned char LogoPIC_data[] = { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 00, 00, 00, 0x0d, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52, 00, 00, 0x05, 00, 00, 00, 0x05, 00, 0x08, 0x06, 00, 00, 00, 0x18, 0xe4, 0xff`

Comment: That's likely a PNG file - see https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/wcbrown/courses/si110AY13S/lec/l31/lec.html Not sure why this is tagged `encryption`

Answer (score 1):

The data (0x89 0x50 ...) that you refer to are not encrypted. It is just a hexadecimal dump of the start of a PNG image. I can tell that from the [Wikipedia PNG entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG#File_format).

The way the data is presented, I mean `unsigned char LogoPIC_data[] = {...}` is how you would format it for inclusion in a C-program header file (a.k.a. include file). This would enable you to embed/store an image in your source file (and thereby in your executable binary) without needing to have a separate, external PNG/JPEG image file.

Assuming your aim is to produce similar-looking outputs for other images, you can do that with `xxd` as follows. If your image is called `image.png`, you would use:

```
xxd -i image.png
```

**Output**

```
 unsigned char image_png[] = {
  0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d,
  0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04,
  0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x89, 0x03, 0xec, 0xb3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x20, 0x63, 0x48, 0x52, 0x4d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7a, 0x26, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80,
  0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0xfa, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0xe8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x75,
  0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0xea, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3a, 0x98, 0x00, 0x00, 0x17,
  0x70, 0x9c, 0xba, 0x51, 0x3c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x50, 0x4c, 0x54,
  0x45, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x41, 0x1d, 0x34, 0x11, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x62, 0x4b, 0x47, 0x44, 0x01, 0xff, 0x02, 0x2d, 0xde,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x74, 0x49, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x07, 0xe7, 0x0c, 0x05,
  0x0f, 0x2d, 0x0c, 0x17, 0x7b, 0xcd, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b, 0x49,
  0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x08, 0xd7, 0x63, 0x60, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08,
  0x00, 0x01, 0x2f, 0x20, 0xdd, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25, 0x74, 0x45,
  0x58, 0x74, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x61, 0x74,
  0x65, 0x00, 0x32, 0x30, 0x32, 0x33, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x32, 0x2d, 0x30, 0x35,
  0x54, 0x31, 0x35, 0x3a, 0x34, 0x35, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x32, 0x2b, 0x30, 0x30,
  0x3a, 0x30, 0x30, 0xd3, 0x8b, 0xd0, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25, 0x74,
  0x45, 0x58, 0x74, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x6d, 0x6f, 0x64, 0x69,
  0x66, 0x79, 0x00, 0x32, 0x30, 0x32, 0x33, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x32, 0x2d, 0x30,
  0x35, 0x54, 0x31, 0x35, 0x3a, 0x34, 0x35, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x32, 0x2b, 0x30,
  0x30, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x30, 0xa2, 0xd6, 0x68, 0xbb, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x28,
  0x74, 0x45, 0x58, 0x74, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6d,
  0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x00, 0x32, 0x30, 0x32, 0x33, 0x2d,
  0x31, 0x32, 0x2d, 0x30, 0x35, 0x54, 0x31, 0x35, 0x3a, 0x34, 0x35, 0x3a,
  0x31, 0x32, 0x2b, 0x30, 0x30, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x30, 0xf5, 0xc3, 0x49, 0x64,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44, 0xae, 0x42, 0x60, 0x82
};
unsigned int image_png_len = 312;
```

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Has a PNG image and wants to make it such that it can be declared as an unsigned char array - presumably for inclusion in a C program. It hits the nail on the head, IMHO - though OP appears to believe it is encryption.

Comment: I get where you're going with this answer, but it needs to include an explanation clear to folks likely to come across this answer in the future. It is not obvious to readers what you've done here, why it's the right answer, or how it applies to the word "encrypted." Knowing the answer, I know what you've done (and it's fine). If I didn't know the answer, I'd be lost.

Comment: @RobNapier and Mr President: Sorry - spending 10 years on StackOverflow makes me spot PNG image dumps quite quickly and it was obvious to me. I take your comments on board and have updated my question with a better explanation.

Comment: Yeah; that's what I was looking for. Thanks.